# Mass softening for high-energy interactions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, mass, higgs, bosons

It is well known (see, e.g., eq. (2) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9803296))  that the coupling $g$ of composite, fermion-bilinear bosons (e.g. pomerons) to fermions (e.g. quarks) decreases above the compositeness scale $\mu$ of these bosons, proportional to the inverse square momentum $k$ that floats through the vertex:

$$g\rightarrow g \,\,\frac{\mu^2}{(\mu^2-k^2)} \,\,\xrightarrow[k^2\gg \mu^2]{\text{}}{} \,\,g \,\,\frac{\mu^2}{(-k^2)}.$$

This intuitively makes sense because composite bosons dissolve in interactions at energies above their compositeness scale.

Now my question is: is this high-energy softening also given for masses, not only for interactions?

In other words, let us consider a highly energetic process, which involves a fermion propagator with a mass given not through the (elementary) Higgs condensate but through a (composite) fermion-bilinear condensate with a compositeness scale much smaller than the process energy. Does this fermion effectively behave as a massless particle in the high-energy process? If so, is the fermion propagator mass energy denpendent,

$$m\rightarrow m \,\,\frac{\mu^2}{(\mu^2-k^2)} \,\,\xrightarrow[k^2\gg \mu^2]{\text{}}{} \,\,m \,\,\frac{\mu^2}{(-k^2)},$$

just as the coupling in the interaction? Or is the mass unaltered for energies above the condensate compositeness scale (and only dissolves for high temperatures / densities as in the early Universe)?